# Join date and time strings into a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Given two strings with the following values:

```
31/05/2013 0:00:00
21:22
```

What's the most efficient way to join them into a `DateTime` data type to get:

```
31/05/2013 21:22
```

The time portion of the first string "0:00:00" is ignored, in favor of using the "time" from the second string.

Comment: With "ignored" you mean that there can be any value?

Comment: Yes, it can be any value like for example "31/05/2013 12:34:12" instead of "31/05/2013 0:00:00"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `TimeSpan` object and `DateTime.Add(yourTimeSpan);` e.g.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013,05,31);
var dts = dt.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 21, 22, 0, 0));
```

Extending the answer a bit, you can parse the date and time first, e.g.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("05/31/2013 0:00:00");
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("21:22");
var dts = dt.Add(ts);
```

...keep in mind, I am not checking for bad date/time values.  If you're unsure if the values are real dates/times, use `DateTime.TryParse` and handle appropriately.

Comment: It's an example concept -- he can just parse it.

Comment: Alternatively he could use the `operator + (DateTime s, TimeSpan t)`

Comment: DateTime.Parse/TryPrase are both very fast too.  TryParse is faster than catching the exceptions that Parse will throw if you get many parsing errors(that's why it exists).  This gets trickier if your dates are not always in the same format though, so hopefully they're consistent, and the globalization context can help you there. Worst case scenario you can use the TryParseExact method, but that is much slower since it has to parse your expression, then parse the date.  Even so, it is still UI fast if a person is entering these strings.

Answer (score 1):

As @George said, parse the first value as a DateTime and then another one as TimeSpan and then add the TimeSpan to first parsed value.

Another option is getting the substring of first 10 charachters of first value and concat it with a space with second value and parse it as DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Say that the first string is called `one` and the second one is called `two`, just do this:

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse(one).Date + DateTime.Parse(two).TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strDate = "31/05/2013 0:00";
string strTime = "21:22";
strDate = strDate.Replace("0:00", strTime);
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting out with just strings, you can just do this:

```
var dateString = "31/05/2013 00:00";
var timeString = "21:22";
var dateTimeString = dateString.Substring(0, 11) + timeString;
var output = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", null);
```

Assuming you know for sure this format won't change (a dangerous assumption, to be sure), this will work. Otherwise, you'd have to parse the date and time strings separately and use conventional date manipulation as others suggested. For example:

```
var ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
var dateString = "31/05/2013 00:00";
var timeString = "21:22";
var output = DateTime.Parse(dateString, ci) + TimeSpan.Parse(timeString, ci);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("31/05/2013 0:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.ParseExact("21:22", "t", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  DateTime result = date + span;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really dealing with only **strings**, then:

```
string strDate = "31/05/2013 0:00:00";
string strTime = "21:22";
string strDateTime = strDate.Split(' ')[0] + " " + strTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely assume you are getting 2 digit month and day, a 4 digit year, and a space after the date:

```
var date = "31/05/2013 0:00:00";
var time = "21:22";
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(date.Substring(0,11) + time);
```

If the assumptions about the input format aren't solid you could use a regex to extract the date instead of `Substring`.